# Android MapView like

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, mapactivity

I would like to implement a Mapview like in my app : 
- A background (the map, tiled or not) which is a Bitmap 
- An overlay with POI

The map should reacts to user zoom/move.

Is it possible to use MapView/MapActivity for this (without connection to Google Maps at all) ?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [mapforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) it lets you use offline maps.